# STM32F103ZET6 ADC with DMA whilst sleeping and interrupt every 0.5s

Tags: stm32, stm32f10x

I am currently trying to get my STM32F1 MCU to ADC 500 samples and DMA these into memory whilst asleep and wakeup after 0.5 seconds, i.e. have a sample from every 0.01s and then wake up after 0.5 seconds to process. I am currently getting a wakeup every 2 seconds. I am unclear of where I am incorrectly seting up my DMA, or less likely the ADC.

I know that my processor is definitely entering into deepsleep as the board goes from 50mA to 30mA, the interrupt i've setup does trigger in debug mode and in my interrupt I have input a delay so I can see it in the scope. Any suggestions on what settings I am missing?

```
// Local Variables
ADC_InitTypeDef     ADC_InitStructure;
DMA_InitTypeDef     DMA_InitStructure;
NVIC_InitTypeDef    NVIC_InitStructure;

// Code
RCC_ADCCLKConfig(RCC_PCLK2_Div6);               // PCLK2 is the APB2 clock ADCCLK = PCLK2/2 = 24/2 = 12MHz
RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_DMA1, ENABLE);      // Enable DMA1 clock so that we can talk to it
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);        // Enable ADC1 clock so that we can talk to it
ADC_DeInit(ADC1);                   // Put everything back to power-on defaults

// DMA1 channel1 configuration
DMA_DeInit(DMA1_Channel1);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr    =  ((uint32_t)0x4001244C);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBaseAddr        =  (uint32_t)&ADC_output;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR           =  DMA_DIR_PeripheralSRC;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize        =  1000;        // Number of samples in buffer
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc     =  DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc         =  DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize    =  DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize        =  DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;     // 0x400 = 1024
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode          =  DMA_Mode_Circular;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority          =  DMA_Priority_High;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_M2M           =  DMA_M2M_Disable;  
DMA_Init(DMA1_Channel1, &DMA_InitStructure);
DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel1, DMA_IT_HT, ENABLE);

// DMA1 NVIC configuration
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA1_Channel1_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;

/* Enable DMA1 NVIC channel1 */
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

/* Enable DMA1 channel1 */
DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel1, ENABLE);

/* ADC1 Configuration */
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Mode          = ADC_Mode_Independent;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode      = ENABLE;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode    = DISABLE;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv      = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T2_CC2;      // Timer 1 ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T1_CC1 / Timer 2 ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T2_CC2
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign         = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfChannel      = 1;                    // Number of ADC channels
ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);

ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

ADC_ResetCalibration(ADC1);
while(ADC_GetResetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));
ADC_StartCalibration(ADC1);
while(ADC_GetCalibrationStatus(ADC1));

// ADC1 regular channels configuration                      // Configure ADC channels to be sampled
ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC1, ADC_Channel_2,   1, ADC_SampleTime_55Cycles5);

ADC_ExternalTrigConvCmd(ADC1, ENABLE);

// TIM1 counter enable                                                                          
// Change if using a different timer trigger
TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);

// TIM1 main Output Enable                                                      // Change if using a different timer trigger
TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM2, ENABLE);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was an issue with the timer that I was using to trigger the ADC not being set to 1000Hz (1ms) and me not enabling both the half and full buffer interrupt.

Fixed Code:

```
DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel1, DMA_IT_HT, ENABLE); 
DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel1, DMA_IT_FT, ENABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Can you provide the fixed code?

Comment: DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel1, DMA_IT_HT, ENABLE);
DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel1, DMA_IT_FT, ENABLE);